# Template member variable typed like generic function

Tags: c++, templates, generics, member

imagine a class like

```
class A 
{
  public:
    template <bool S>
    A(X<S> x) : x(x) { }

 private:
    X<S> x;
}
```

Via argument deduction, the constructor of class A can deduce the value of S. An example would be:

```
void f() {
  X<true> x;
  A a(x);
}
```

The problem is that the private member x does not know anything about S. Is there a way to 'pass' the value of S to the member variable?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The short answer is: no, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Think of it this way: `sizeof(A)` must be known before any instance of `A` is constructed. So the composition of the class cannot possibly depend on which constructor is used for a particular instance. You can use some form of type erasure, e.g. `std::variant`, to have particular instances hold different data.

Answer (score 1):

The only way the static type `class A` can depend on something like the `S` in the type of its member is if it is templated on that:

```
template<bool S>
class A 
{
  public:
    A(X<S> x) : x(x) { }

 private:
    X<S> x;
};
```

Although the type in `f` would then need to be `A<true>`, in C++17 we can be just as terse as before:

```
void f() {
  X<true> x;
  A a(x);
}
```